# Installing ode using Macports

Tags: xcode, macports, ode-library

I am trying to install ode via Macports, but get this error:

```
On Mac OS X 10.5, ode 0.11.1 requires Xcode 3.1 or later but you have Xcode 3.0.
Error: Target org.macports.extract returned: incompatible Xcode version
```

Is there any way to install ode without xcode 3.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can download XCode 3.1.x for Leopard @ http://connect.apple.com (registration required).

That might be the easiest way, or are you staying on 3.0 for a specific reason?

You could always try to alter / remove `minimum_xcodeversion` in the portfile itself, although chances are your compilation will then probably fail (somebody had a reason for adding it).

Comment: I don't want to have to uninstall my current version of XCode (which I got from disk) then have to get an apple developer connection account and reinstall XCode from the internet. I don't understand why xcode effects ode. I wouldn't even be using it from xcode. I just want it so that I can use PyODE.

Comment: Search for your local copy of the ode portfile then and comment out the relevant bit (insert `#` at the start of the  line with `minimum_xcodeversion`, save, try reinstalling the portfile). On my Snow Leopard system (macports updated via rsync) it's in `/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/ports/devel/ode` but your paths may be different (try using finder to find an ode directory)

Comment: You can use `port dir ode` to get the directory of `ode`, so, e.g., `cd $(port dir ode)` will take you to the directory. You can also use `port edit ode` to open the Portfile in an editor.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode includes gcc and all the other developer command line tools - the minimum requirement for Xcode 3.1 is probably because a minimmum version of gcc is required. You should really just bit the bullet and get the latest Xcode (3.2.2) from http://connect.apple.com - it only takes a few minutes to download and install (depending on how fast your broadband connection is).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [change log](http://trac.macports.org/changeset/47097/trunk/dports/devel/ode/Portfile) for the `ode` Portfile, the minimum Xcode version was set to remove a libGL workaround. I suppose you could check out the [patch](http://trac.macports.org/changeset/47097/trunk/dports/devel/ode/Portfile) and undo that change on the local copy of your Portfile, and see if that works.